# How do I use a comparator (for a binary search) to compare a DateTime to a DateTime field in an object?

Tags: java, comparator

I want to compare inputted dates to a sorted list of holidays objects using a binary search. The holiday objects consist of a string with the name and a jodatime Datetime. So I am comparing the same types but one is part of an object and the other is not.

I have:

```
public class DateTimeComparator implements Comparator<DateTime> {
    public int compare(DateTime userDate, DateTime listHoliday) {
        if (userDate.equals(Holidays.getAllHolidays().date)) {
        return 1;
        }
        else {
        return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Eclipse's feedback is that date can't be resolved. How can I correctly point to the date field of my Holiday list?

Edit: So if I don't need a comparator (suggested to me in another question), how do I structure my binary search? So far I have:

```
public static boolean isHoliday(List<Holiday> holidayList, DateTime date) {
        if(Collections.binarySearch(holidayList.date, date)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, "instant holidays". That is a new concept...

Comment: @fge, I don't follow. I am using the joda-time library for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a `Comparator` for this, `DateTime`s are already inherently `Comparable`.  Also, referencing the `date` field for a LIST is non-sensical; its the ELEMENTS of the list with have that field, not the list itself.

You want to use [Collections.binarySearch](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_binarysearch_comparable.htm) instead, and handle the output yourself.

Comment: That makes sense, but the linked tutorial doesn't have the field that is being searched for in an object. How do I reference the elements of the list without using a for loop? (See edited question).

Comment: You can't, sadly, not until Java8 anyway.  However, if you make your Holiday object Comparable with DateTime, you wouldn't have to (not sure if you want to do that, though)

Comment: I am trying to make my Holiday comparable to DateTime but I am failing. PS Isn't java 8 out?

Comment: Hehe, so it is - forgot about that.  It's only been out for 5 days though, I believe.  You can look up Streams API to see how to convert a List without a for loop with Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a new holiday and comparing two holiday objects to each other with a comparator that looks at the DateTime field.